# On save navigate to record detail page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningnavigation

I'm a starter in lightning, I have created a component contains input fields of a custom object (`session__c`) and used that component as a quick action in the Account record page. On clicking of quick action I'm able to save a new record of `session__c`.

Here is what I'm struggling, on saving the record it must navigate to `session__c` object record detail page not to account detail page, but I don't know the functionality of it.

Can someone please let me know how to navigate to record detail page in lightning component ?

Comment: how did you save session__c record? by LDS/`lighting:recordeditform` ?where you struck? can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [`lightning:navigation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) and the [`standard__recordPage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) page reference type here. Once the record has been saved and you have the record id (*you will need to have this for the component to work*), you can redirect the flow to that specific record page.

Here's a snippet from the docs with relevant modification which will help you achieve the result. Note that you will need to adjust this accordingly. For further implementation details/example, refer to the docs linked.

In your component, you declare the `lightning:navigation`and then utilize in the JS:

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

And then in the JS, once the record has been saved, just navigate to that record's id. Note that you will need to get the id of the record.

```
var navService = cmp.find("navService");

var pageReference = {
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
        recordId: 'the id of the record', // this is what you will need
        actionName: 'View',
        objectApiName: 'session__c' // the object's api name
    }
};

navService.navigate(pageReference);
```